# Ship only a percentage of logs to logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, nxlog

How can I configure filebeat to only ship a percentage of logs (a sample if you will) to logstash?

In my application's log folder the logs are chunked to about 20 megs each. I want filebeat to ship only about 1/300th of that log volume to logstash.

I need to pare down the log volume before I send it over the wire to logstash so I cannot do this filtering from logstash it needs to happen on the endpoint before it leaves the server.

I asked this question in the ES forum and someone said it was not possible with filebeat: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ship-only-a-percentage-of-logs-to-logstash/77393/2

Is there really no way I can extend filebeat to do this? Can nxlog or another product to this?

Comment: Yes, NXLog can do this and it's low footprint. You can filter and drop() based on various conditions (e.g. regex ).

Comment: hmmm regex? Not sure if that's gonna work, I don't want to filter types of messages out I want to only send a percentage of the same type of messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to configure Filebeat to drop arbitrary events based on a probability. But Filebeat does have the ability to drop events based on conditions. There are two way to filter events.

Filebeat has a way to specify lines to include or exclude when reading the file. This is the most efficient place to apply the filtering because it happens early. This is done using `include_lines` and [`exclude_lines`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html#exclude-lines) in the config file.

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- paths:
  - /var/log/myapp/*.log
  exclude_lines: ['^DEBUG']
```

All Beats have ["processors"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-processors.html) that allow you to apply an action based on a condition. One action is `drop_events` and the conditions are `regexp`, `contains`, `equals`, and `range`.

```
processors:
- drop_event:
    when:
      regexp:
        message: '^DEBUG'
```

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to filter out specific lines, the lines that I want will be of a huge volume so I want to ship only a percentage. Could I do something with drop_event and a condition that would cause it to only send x % of logs over a period of time?

Comment: Could I: Set a variable with a timestamp. Then the condition would be send logs if current time < ( timestamp + 5mins ). If current time > ( timestamp + 5mins ) don't send logs until current time == (current time + 30mins). Then set the timestamp variable again and start over. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do that with FileBeat. You *can* do it with Logstash, though.

```
filter {
  drop {
    percentage => 99.7
  }
}
```

This may be a use-case where you would use Logstash in shipping mode on the server, rather than FileBeat.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/hugelogs/*.log"
    add_tags => [ 'sampled' ]
  }
}

filter {
  drop {
    percentage => 99.7
  }
}

output {
  tcp {
    host =>  'logstash.prod.internal'
    port =>  '3390'
  }
}
```

It means installing Logstash on your servers. However, you configure it as minimally as possible. Just an input, enough filters to get your desired effect, and a single output (Tcp in this case, but it could be anything). Full filtering will happen down the pipeline.

Comment: I thought the log shipping version of logstash was deprecated.

Comment: @red888 It is, however Logstash itself can be configured to ship. It's not as low footprint as FIleBeat, but it will get the job done. It's how we do it.